# Duplicate symbols for architecture armv7-

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

I'm working on game engine using C++ language and now I'm trying to solve strange linker errors.

```
duplicate symbol __Z11SplitSpringRKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEEcRNS_6vectorIS5_NS3_IS5_EEEE in:
.../Debug-iphoneos/Maze.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ObjectComplex.o
```

And in some other modules. Totally I have 25 duplicate symbols in different modules.
This is what I have checked so far:

- including code file instead of header
- having same interface name in different headers
- having static variables in header file
- having duplicate source code files in compile sources
- also tried rebuilding of the entire solution

I'm using third-party libraries but they are statically linked so i doubt that they could be source of the problem.
Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you *define* e.g. the function `SplitString` in a header file without using `static` or `inline`.

Comment: No, I have no idea where it went from. I don't have any functions or identifiers named `SplitString` in my project.

Comment: Is there any way you could narrow down the problem, then post the offending code?

Comment: But I have defined a macro which references the singleton instance which is obviously static. Could it cause such a problem?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg, you were right, my bad! I have a function that should be static but it's not. And since I made a typo in it's name I didn't find it at first. Tank you for giving me the clue! Consider the question answered.